# Statsmodels package in Python - issues with retrieving out-of-sample prediction of ARIMA model

Tags: python, forecasting, statsmodels

I'm trying to retrieve an out-of-sample prediction for ARIMA model. However, I constantly receive errors and I'm not sure how should I proceed now:( The code is the following:

```
    from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
    fit = ARIMA(endog, (1,1,1)).fit()
    params = fit.params
    forecast = fit.predict(params.all(), start='2015-9-21', end='2016-9-21', typ='levels')
```

It worked well (i.e. giving me a result, but not an out-of-sample one...) when I only used

```
    forecast = fit.predict(params.all(), typ='levels')
```

but when I added "start" and "end" dates (or only "start") it doesn't want to work, I constantly get errors. In case of the first cited chunk of code its: "TypeError: predict() got multiple values for keyword argument 'start'". I also tried with datetime type and it also didn't work. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: There were several fixes for this since 0.6. For example end datetime wasn't supported https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2587 I don't remember any problems with start date. However, the problem might be that the predict method of the results instance doesn't have `params` as an argument. try `fit.predict(start='2015-9-21', end='2016-9-21', typ='levels')`

Comment: Hello! Thank you for a tip - I tried without params as an argument and this time got error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_loc' " :(

Comment: @MBseekingforhelp do you get the answer already? I got "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_loc' " too

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error to the one reported above:

`"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_loc' "`

But I realised this was because I was passing an array (or list) without a datetime index, e.g. if you use pandas dataframes and input it as `df.values`, then you drop the time index, and ARMA doesn't have the dates information (so dates is None) which triggers this error. I suggest you feed in a `pd.DataFrame` or `pd.Series` object with a datetime index. See also this thread http://pystatsmodels.narkive.com/rhX3T509/arma-predict-throws-attributeerror-with-start-and-end-dates

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
fit.forecast(steps, exog=None, alpha=0.05)
```

where `steps=365` according to your `start` and `end` parameter if its on monthly basis.
Refer to the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49988200/8245191)